# AWS SDK 2.0 Ruby Presigned URL & transcoding the content after upload

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, transcoding

My intention:

1. Get the presigned URL for posting a resource
2. Post resource to S3 bucket
3. Transcode my resource on s3 (for video files)

I have figured out 1 & 2 from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLRubySDK.html) after hitting the route, say /getPresignedURL. Has anyone done 3?

My backup plan is to create another route, say /fileUpload which upon successful upload to the presignedURL will return a 200. I will then run a job for transcoding the video, manually. Any easier way to do this? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/SettingBucketNotifications.html). When your video has just uploaded into S3 bucket, you can trigger an [AWS Lambda](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/lambda/) function to process your S3 object.

If you have a long video file, you can ask AWS Lambda function to call [AWS Elastic Transcoder](http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/). The price is quite expensive (it depends on your need and budget).

If your video is short, you can use AWS Lambda function to directly transcode the video. I found [binoculars/aws-lambda-ffmpeg](https://github.com/binoculars/aws-lambda-ffmpeg) project on Github. But, I've never tried it before.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for your suggestion.